# Is it possible to do static code analysis for python using SonarQube?

Tags: python, sonarqube, syntax-error, sonar-runner, static-code-analysis

I need to check for errors in my python files before building the project. Is this possible using SonarQube? If Yes, what checks are performed for Python(syntax, indentation, import errors, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube Analyzers assume they're scanning compilable code. Pylint checks are available but off by default. For a full list of built-in rules, see the [SonarAnalyzer for Python rule report](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/rules/python_rules_coverage.html).